# Convert an epoch timestamp from a list of dictionary to a list of HH:MM:SS

Tags: ansible

I have a list of dictionaries with the following structure

```py
data= [
        {
           data: [int]
           timestamps: [int]
           stat: "string"
        }
      ]
```

the timestamps are in epoch time, and I'm having trouble iterating through the list and converting each dictionaries list of timestamps to `HH:MM:SS`.

In my main playbook I have the following:

*main.yml*

```yaml
- name: reformat times
  include_tasks: convert-time.yml
  loop: "{{ data }}"
```

*convert-time.yml*

```yaml
---
- name: set empty list
  set_fact:
    timestamps: []

- name: convert epoch time
  set_fact:
    timestamps: "{{ timestamps + ['%H:%M:%S' | strftime(item/1000)] }}"
  loop: "{{ item['timestamps'] }}"
```

Here I want a task that sets the original dictionaries `timestamps` key to the timestamps list, so, essentially

```py
item['timestamps'] = timestamps**
```

I have tried

```yaml
- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    item['timestamps']: "{{ timestamps }}"
```

but this clearly is a major syntax error.

Comment: Could you provide a real example of `data` you are getting? You could use a `- debug: var=data` and provide the output in an [edit] of your quesition. At first glance the part that is very dubious in your code is the `loop: "{{ item['timestamps'] }}"`. If you are getting any error message, please also provide them in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Although your problem is solvable by using only Ansible filters and tasks, this is a case where writing a few lines of python as a [custom filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins) probably makes sense.

---

<sup>Note: the major difficulty to solve this easily and correctly without having to rely on a supplementary task is that the [ansible `strftime` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/strftime_filter.html) expects the format string as first parameter and the timestamp as second, hence making it impossible to use efficiently with the  [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) with a list of timestamps as an entry. See for example [this feature request/discussion on github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/46340) for a better understanding of the problem.</sup>

---

Create the file `filter_plugins/my_data_filters.py` adjacent to your playbook. See [this other answer](/a/12400584/9401096) as a reference for epoch->string conversion. This is a quickNdirty implementation which should be enhanced with data validation and error management for production.

```py
from time import strftime, localtime


def epoch2hours(data):
    """
    Expects a list of dictionary with keys data, timestamp and stat
    The timestamp key in each element is expected to be an epoch
    Returns the same dictionary adding a timestamp_hours key
    containing epoch converted to HH:MM:SS for the given day
    """
    result = []
    for entry in data:
        entry["timestamp_hours"] = strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime(entry["timestamp"]))
        result.append(entry)
    return result


class FilterModule(object):
    """my data filters."""

    def filters(self):
        """Return the filter list."""
        return {
            'epoch2hours': epoch2hours
        }
```

Then the following `test_data_filters.yml` playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    data:
      - data: 1
        timestamp: 1697892451
        stat: today
      - data: 11
        timestamp: 1697806069
        stat: yesterday
      - data: 111
        timestamp: 1695304088
        stat: a month ago
      - data: 1111
        timestamp: 1666360103
        stat: a year ago

    data_with_hours: "{{ data | epoch2hours }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show the entire data with hours
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: data_with_hours

    - name: Get the hours only
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: data_with_hours | map(attribute='timestamp_hours')
```

gives

```
$ ansible-playbook test_data_filters.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show the entire data with hours] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "data_with_hours": [
        {
            "data": 1,
            "stat": "today",
            "timestamp": 1697892451,
            "timestamp_hours": "14:47:31"
        },
        {
            "data": 11,
            "stat": "yesterday",
            "timestamp": 1697806069,
            "timestamp_hours": "14:47:49"
        },
        {
            "data": 111,
            "stat": "a month ago",
            "timestamp": 1695304088,
            "timestamp_hours": "15:48:08"
        },
        {
            "data": 1111,
            "stat": "a year ago",
            "timestamp": 1666360103,
            "timestamp_hours": "15:48:23"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Get the hours only] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "data_with_hours | map(attribute='timestamp_hours')": [
        "14:47:31",
        "14:47:49",
        "15:48:08",
        "15:48:23"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: So how would I implement this when utilizing roles, with a generic playbook/roles file structure.

Comment: Are your roles standalone or in collection(s) ? You basically do the same thing as above except the filter goes in your standalone role or in your collection. For a standalone role see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure. For a collection see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_collections_structure.html. If this is not fixed yet, I suggest you go for collection. this will make callling your filter more explicit with your namespace (e.g. `companyXYZ.awesomecollection.epoch2hours`)